# Will this Relay circuit work?

Tags: relay

I have a truck on which the rear turn signals are not very visible when the parking lamps are on. So I am trying to get the parking lamps to turn off while the turn signal is on. Below is the wiring diagram that I am planning to use and I just need a professional confirmation that it will work.
The bulb I am using draws 2.2 Amps.
I have learnt from this forum that a regular auto relay which is 30A rated may be an overkill as the current draw of the coil is a couple amps.
So I am planning to use this 10A PCB relay.
https://www.e-sonic.com/product-detail/mode/505330.html?p=45319483

Will this work, and is the relay suitable?
Also, I am assuming I do not need a flyback diode with this relay, correct?

Your input is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your schematic and the selection  of the relay is great, make sure you enclose the relay very well. You don't really need a flyback diode since the current operating the coil is really low (400Ohm@12V drains 30mA, amazing).

If you have any questions or problems feel free to leave them below.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your input Marcelo, much appreciated.